# Avoid <img>'s source of being downloaded - is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add a flip-book-plugin (e.g. http://www.turnjs.com/) on my page. All plugins like that uses a raw `<img>` tags where I can see the URL & download the image. I want to avoid that scenario (I don't want to allow users to download that images) To do so, I've started wondering about some protection.

And here I need some tips how can I do that.

I was thinking about dynamic generating the whole page. But, if I load async the page I can get the URL (e,g via FireBug)

...or use empty `<img>` tags where I will load dynamically theirs content ?

Comment: Any asset that is available to the browser will be available to the user. That goes for images, stylesheets, scripts etc. You can't stop someone from downloading an image.

Comment: They don't even have to try very hard: just open your browser's developer tools and navigate to where it gives you a list of *everything* it has been instructed to fetch. It doesn't matter what hoops you jump through before instructing the browser to do so.

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule, anything you provide as an asset to a web page cannot be secured. Images, CSS / JS files, Flash SWFs, what have you. When your browser loads a page, all the assets in the layout will be downloaded.

While that's performed silently and behind-the-scenes, fact remains that those files are already in the client's computer. That point forward, there's no stopping a crafty user from acquiring your files (because, by the sole nature of browsing, he/she *already has*).

Answer (score 2):

As all people here mentioned: A user will always be able to download any asset that is available for their browser – in fact, they already did if the see your page.

Anyways, what you could do is preventing the visitor from download an image you already delivered a 2nd time by invalidating the URL of the image.
This needs a little scripting on your server:

1. When delivering your HTML page create a unique token for every image that you want to "protect" with each request to your page. Store it in a cache (or database) together with the identifier of the image (like the local path of the image on your server or the id of the image's representation in your database). Do not put the "real" url of the image in your HTML or JavaScript but instead use something like: `<img src="http://yourdomain.com/images/#TOKEN" alt="protected image">` or `<img src="http://yourdomain.com/images/imageHandler.jpg?requestID=#TOKEN" alt="protected image">`
2. The browser will try to load the resource from the img's src URL. If you get a request for that resource on your server deliver the image and remove the token from the cache immediately. If you can't find the token in your cache deliver an error page like *"Your download token for this resource has already been used"*.
3. Make sure you deliver the image with appropriate cache control headers (see: [HTTP/1.1 Header Field Definitions for Cache Control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9)). This should prevent the browser from storing the image to the hard disk. (Be aware: browsers will always try to achieve best performance for their users, so don't count on it – but since this is a must-respect-header according to the http-standards my guess is a browser will only store the image in memory.)

This way, a user that simply copies the `<img>`'s src and tries a download will just get to the error page. The url is no longer valid because his browser has already used it for downloading the image before.

By the way, this is how most of those file sharing and online video stream services protect their download links. Just one token per request and resource, the token is removed as soon as the resource is delivered. If there is no token then there is no resource and the real URL of the resource never has to be revealed, in fact there is no need for any "real" URL.

Still: this is security by obscurity. But in 80% of the cases this will prevent users from downloading your image.

Comment: sounds good but what I user clicks on the loaded image and selects Save Image As context-menu option ?

Comment: depends on the browser – some will try to reload and start a download some will just save it to disk from their memory cache... it's a good idea by the way to put the image as a css background-image in a properly sized div instead of using the img tag.

Comment: but if the image will be a div background I'll have to put the valid url('/images/myimage.png'). Without that token ?

Comment: one more thing – it's a really nasty one: you can also place a div with the same size of the image right above the image and give it a 1x1px transparent png as background image – even firefox will then just store the blank png when the user tries a "Save Image As" – they will have to open the developer console and remove the covering div from the DOM-Tree by hand in order to use the context menu. I've seen pages doing that and monitoring with a java script if the cover is removed – then they also removed the image... still all useless cause there are many ways to get the to image...

Comment: no, you don't will work with the token url as well – i recommend a good rewrite rule and deliver the image via some url schema like this: http://blabla.com/images/theImagesName#TOKEN.jpg – also search engines may like this url pattern cause there is some "catchy" name

Comment: do You know some site exaples about that 1x1px backgruond image and tje JS monitoring ? And also, I think I can override that JS method using the FireBug's console

Comment: as mentioned earlier if you want the image – you'll get it! there is no way to prevent a user from finally getting the image all you can do is make it more complicated. But that makes it more complicated on your site of the game too. Why not just delivering an image with _"quality as good as needed for the page but too poor to do anything else with it"_. Examplepage: Just have a look at some of these video portals – many of them do that to cover the flash player

Answer (score 0):

All images will be downloaded by browser anyway. So user can get access to it.
If you want to restrict this, probably you can use Flash with some kind of encryption (I didn't work with flash well).

Comment: the user could as well download the flash and access it anytime though this requires a little more effort.

Comment: Of course you can obfuscate your swf but you can't protect it completely. The word "Encryption" is 1) per definition reversable 2) often misused in advertisements like these to give a feeling of security which in real can't be provided.